# Join in Zend Framework using alias

Tags: php, zend-framework, join, zend-db, zend-db-table

How to do the query:

```
$name = $this->_dbTable->info('name');
$result = $this->_dbTable->select()->from($name)->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$result->join(array('t' => "$name.tipo")), "t.id = $name.id");
```

Where '$name.tipo' is the table name for join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't join to a different table per row, depending on the value of `tipo`.  SQL requires that the tables be fixed at the time you prepare the query, the table can't change as the data values fetched from a given column are discovered.

Your design is called [*Polymorphic Associations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymorphic-associations), and it's a non-relational design.  It's very awkward to do this in SQL.

See my presentation [Practical Object Oriented Models In SQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql) for some alternatives.